# 空のディレクトリのバイトサイズ

Tags: operating-system

macOS、Linux、およびWindows上の空のディレクトリの標準サイズはどれくらいですか？各オペレーティングシステムで同じサイズですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

空のディレクトリーのサイズはオペレーティングシステムでは一概に決められず、それぞれのOSのそれぞれのドライブが採用しているファイルシステムで決まると思います。
　有名なところでは
* unix系で多く（絶対ではない）採用されているi-node
* Soralis系で採用されていて、時期unix系OSの主要ファイルシステムになる事を期待されているZFS
* Windows系もNTFSやFAT、FAT32など複数のファイルシステムが混在しています
* macOSではafs,apfsなど今現在一つのOSでもドライブの初期化時にファイルシステムを選ぶことが出来る

など様々で数え出すとキリがないので、標準サイズと言えるものは無いと思います
一つ言えるのはディレクトリー名もディレクトリ情報と考えるならディレクトリー名で可変なので、ますます決まったサイズはないと言えるかと思います。